# How do I fit this pair of chain tensioners on my single speed bike?

Tags: chain, single-speed, dropouts, tension

I have these chain tensioners:
[image]

How do I install them correctly on my single speed bike? Do they go on the inside or outside of the frame?

My dropouts look something like this:

[image]

Apologies if the answer is really obvious. Appreciate the help.

Comment: The bolt is on the open end of the dropout and the axle goes thru the hole

Answer (score 9):

They look like you want those "in" the horizontal dropout. The bracket should cover the frame and as you tighten the bolt it will pull the axle further away from the cranks, tightening the chain along with it.

[image]

Be careful to not over tighten as you want a little 'slack' in the chain. Also, it is very easy to tighten one side more than the other resulting in your wheel not rolling straight (just slightly off center is what I see most often).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, to clarify the tensioners should be fitted on the outside of the frame?

Comment: Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_end#mediaviewer/File:Chaintug.jpg

Comment: Not on the outside, not on the inside, but in the horizontal area of the dropout, the bracket will be on the rear of the dropout on the frame. The photo that @mattnz added shows a similar chain tensioner.

Comment: @GlennGervais so do the "eyes" of the tensioner go on the outside of the frame?

Comment: Can't see the pics here, but almost definitely outside. The "inside" gap should already match the hub width, so there's no space.

Comment: @NickT the "eyes" go in the dropout. 

Not on the outside and as Emyr said, not the inside as it should match the hub width so no room on the inside.

Comment: @GlennGervais I am *super* confused when you say "in the dropout". The OD of the eyelet is way bigger than the dropout slot (the ID is what matches), so the only way it could fit inside is if you put it at some strange angle (then there's no way the axle could fit)

Comment: @NickT This style of chain tensioner might not work with your frame. The image that mattnz found shows the 'slot' on the inside of the dropout. I agree that it is confusing, most frames don't have this slot or accommodate this style of tensioner

Comment: Those tensioners will definitely work with the frame shown, and will go together as shown in the photo in this answer. The "washer" part goes on the outside of the frame, since as Emyr says, there should be no room on the inside.